# Which tripod plates are compatible with the Nikon D7000?

Tags: nikon, tripod

I'm searching for D7000 compatible tripod in local online market. 
D7000 body doesn't have small whole near the screw as shown below (well it has but pretty far).
[image]

However, in the local market whatever I hit has some small element near the main screw.

[image]
[image]
[image]

So can somebody show the plate(s) which are compatible with nikon? What is the standard name for Nikon's plate and what is the standard on plates shown above?

Comment: Glad to hear I'm not the only one with this problem. I simply push the safety pin out. On my model (Manfrotto 384PL-14) I removed it from the top of the plate (the part with the rubber area that goes against the camera body). I grabbed a small precision screwdriver to use as a lever and push the safety pin up.![Removed pin][1]

Comment: possible duplicate http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15775/how-do-i-fasten-a-nikon-d90-to-a-tripod-head-with-camera-alignment-pin

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That pin that you've circled will be a spring loaded pin that will retract.  Some cameras may have a hole that pin will fit into to keep the camera from swiveling, but if the camera has no hole, the pin will retract and won't be in the way.

By the way, the pictured tripod looks pretty light.  If you have a large lens on your D7000 that tripod will probably work, but doesn't look like a really sturdy tripod.  You can read up on recommendations [here](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/2505/what-should-i-pay-attention-to-when-choosing-a-tripod)

Comment: Thanks for the link, I went through it and it's useful. It's 3 different tripods. The links is here http://www.11st.co.kr/product/SellerProductDetail.tmall?method=getSellerProductDetail&prdNo=73031977 and they claim that it can handle up to 4.8Kg of load. The heaviest lens I have is 18-200. Do you still think it's too light?

Comment: You camera + lens will be well under the limit.  But it's not a matter of whether it can hold your lens, it won't collapse under the weight, it's whether it will be steady enough and not wobble, or tip over in a bit of wind.  For casual use it might be fine, depends on what you plan to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that those tripods don't look very sturdy!  I have a similar sized camera to the D7000 and use the Manfrotto system for my tripod.  The plate I have looks like the one in this photo:

[image]

Incidentally this is the same head I use too, the MH054M0-Q2 - and it's incredible! I love it, and can highly recommend it!  I'm using it on a set of 055CXPRO3 legs which make the whole thing very lightweight and strong, and it easily holds my 7D with 100-400mm telephoto with no problem at all.

Note that the plate comes included with the head, but you can also buy extras separately in any good camera shop. I bought an extra one for mine, and often when my mate & I go shooting I give him my spare plate for his camera so we can both use my tripod without fuss.

Comment: +1 mentionning the manfrotto system which I use for smaller range. this brand is the better value I found (price / quality rate).