# What is the purpose of the second bump on the plate of this tripod?

Tags: tripod, tripod-heads

I am planning to buy a used Velbon CX-660 tripod for outdoor shooting with my Pentax K-x. What is the purpose of the bump on this tripod plate?

[image: Velbon CX-660 Tripod plate]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I fasten a Nikon D90 to a tripod head with camera alignment pin?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/15775/how-do-i-fasten-a-nikon-d90-to-a-tripod-head-with-camera-alignment-pin)

Comment: Also: [Which tripod plates are compatible with the Nikon D7000?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/q/19037/15871)

Comment: The specific camera models may be different, but the basic question is exactly the same.

Answer (score 5):

This is an alignment pin. This pin dovetails into a receiving hollow built into the base of most video cameras. The idea is to prevent unwanted camera movement that otherwise might occur when panning. Additionally, when the camera is dismounted and remounted, this pin affords accurate repositioning. 
Additionally, many video and still cameras are mounted to a tripod via a quick release mechanism. These allow rapid camera attachment and detachment. The locator pin helps insure the remounted camera is accurately aligned as before.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Marcus. But since my Pentax k-x does not have such a hole, I suppose that pin goes simply downside, or?

Comment: @ Kini Mladenov --- Life has its ups and downs.

Answer (score 0):

I can answer the title of the question - "What is the purpose of the second bump on the plate of this tripod" but your actual question differs greatly

The bump is designed to prevent or reduce rotation of the camera on the tripod plate. For example, my Canon 80D has ridges on its base which the bump would protrude into and prevent rotation of the camera.

Often they are sprung, to make them adjustable for different cameras

Comment: So it can be adjusted, ok, thanks. Because my camera, for example does not have ridges